# C++ std::regex_replace rgx and fmt arguments to add a leading zero to exponent in scientific notation?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, visual-c++

Problem: With the VS 2015 compiler, sprintf prints only two characters for the exponent in scientific notation. I want to print three characters like the VS 2012 compiler does. My solution is to post-process the formatted string using the std::regex_replace function. What do I need to enter for the rgx pattern and fmt replace format string to add a leading zero to the exponent, but not change anything else in the string s?

```
// http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <regex>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

void addLeadingZeroToExponentsFailsToWork() {
    // If exponents have only 2 characters, then add a leading zero.
    std::string s("X: 5.600000e-05 dm2; Y: 3.466654e+07 dm2; Z: 5.430000e-08 dm2;");
    std::regex rgx("(-?\\d+\\.\\d+e[-|+])(\\d{2}\\s+)");
    std::string fmt("$1 0$2");
    std::string res = std::regex_replace(s, rgx, fmt);
    std::cout << res << std::endl << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}

// fmt("$10$2") ==> X: 05 dm2; Y: 07 dm2; Z: 08 dm2;
// fmt("$1 0$2") ==> X: 05.600000e- 005 dm2; Y: 03.466654e+ 007 dm2; Z: 05.430000e- 008 dm2;
// What rgx and fmt? ==> X: 5.600000e-005 dm2; Y: 3.466654e+007 dm2; Z: 5.430000e-008 dm2;

// Below is my updated function based on the accepted answer from Laszlo:

#define BELL "\007"

void addLeadingZeroToExponents() {
    // If exponents have only 2 characters, then add a leading zero.
    const std::string s("X: -5.600000e-15 dm2; Y: +3.466654e+07 dm2; Z: 5.430000e-08 dm2;");
    const std::regex rgx("([-+]?\\d+\\.\\d+e[-+])(\\d{2}\\s+)");
    // Inserting a zero directly does not seem to be possible without a positive look-behind assertion,
    // which C++11 does not have. So first insert some character (BELL) that will never appear in
    // the input string, and then replace that character with a zero.
    const std::string fmt("$1" BELL "$2");
    const std::string res = std::regex_replace(std::regex_replace(s, rgx, fmt), std::regex(BELL), "0");
    std::cout << res << std::endl << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}

int main()
{
    addLeadingZeroToExponents();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They finally fixed that bug?

Comment: Three digits in the exponent. The C standard requires 2 when the absolute value of the exponent is less than 100. MS has gotten this wrong since forever.

Comment: I don't want to get into a discussion of what the standard says. No matter what it says, I still want to make the new exponents match the old exponents to reduce the noise level when comparing results from the two compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is not that elegant, but it produces the desired output. It needs a character, that does not occur elsewhere within the input string.

```
#define BELL "\007"

void addLeadingZeroToExponentsBell() {
   // If exponents have only 2 characters, then add a leading zero.
   std::string s("X: 5.600000e-05 dm2; Y: 3.466654e+07 dm2; Z: 5.430000e-08 dm2;");
   std::regex rgx("([-|+]?\\d+\\.\\d+e[-|+])(\\d{2}\\s+)");

   std::string fmt("$1" BELL "$2");
   std::string res = std::regex_replace(std::regex_replace(s, rgx, fmt), std::regex(BELL), "0");

   std::cout << res << std::endl << std::endl;
   system("pause");
}
```

Comment: very interesting. I will try it, but I would need to find a character that will never occur in the actual output, which is much more extensive than this simple example. Maybe it could be some non-printable control character?

Comment: BELL (ASCII 7) should work IMHO. (Edited the answer accordingly.)

Comment: Yes, I did a quick test, and this does work. I will do a real-world test at work on Monday. If nobody provides a more elegant solution on Monday, I will award the checkmark to Laszlo. Thanks!

Comment: It passed my real-world test. In my real-world implementation, I measured a 2-5% performance hit from the addLeadingZeroToExponents function, which should be acceptable. I added an updated function to my question based on Laszlo's accepted answer.